# Logout not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am not able to logout my current user from the browser mode of the rest api.

This is my settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
               'PAGINATE_BY': 10,  
                 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (  
                      'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',  
                      'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',  
                      'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  
                                                 ),  
                  'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (  
                      'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',  
                                      ),  
                 }
```

Is it because i used sessions? Pls help.

The Request and response headers:

```
Request URL:`http://localhost:8000/api/api-auth/logout/?next=/api/city/`   
Request Method:GET  
Status Code:302 FOUND  
Request Headers:
---------------
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch  
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8  
Connection:keep-alive  
Cookie:sessionid=j7qebcdjdwzwqlmep4eyq3svuial43uv; csrftoken=vK3Ghn3QFVbCe3nKx1LDZBTzM7sRiDym  
Host:127.0.0.1:8000  
Referer:`http://localhost:8000/api/city/`
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36  
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded  
next:/api/city/  
Response Headers  
----------------
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8  
Date:Mon, 15 Jul 2013 20:46:35 GMT  
Location:`http://localhost:8000/api/city/`  
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4  
Set-Cookie:sessionid=b1x24z93dqu384lqirtv5r9npy16s0qx; expires=Mon, 29-Jul-2013 20:46:35 GMT;  httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Vary:Cookie
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solved It! It was because of BasicAuthentication being enabled. I guess i logged in via HTTP login in browser and logout doesnt seem to work for that.I removed BasicAuthentication and everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: By commenting BasicAuthentication it worked well as long as I was using generics, when I switched back to APIView I am still unable to logout

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem today and solved it by changing the order to the following:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
```

Comment: Not sure if the changing of order to Session, Basic works. Not for me. :(

Answer (score 4):

Actually logout is working, but during the redirect (to a view that requires authentication, because we use permission IsAuthenticated) at the end of logout, BasicAuth auth the request again using cached HTTP authentication header information:

```
auth = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', b'')
```

So like OP said, we can disable BasicAuth and use SessionAuth only. But the thing is, we sometimes may need to access API without GUI, we can use TokenAuth instead. Since BasicAuth/TokenAuth is not so secure anyway (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), it might be better that we use OAuth2 or other more secure auth schemes. It depends on the demands anyway.